# is there any scenario where hashtable is better than concurrenthashmap?

Tags: java, collections

As we all know that ConcurrentHashMap is better in performance but can we have any scenario where Hashtable is better?

Comment: You should compare apples to apples, which means `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())` and `ConcurrentHashMap`. `Hashtable` is nothing but legacy and there were many improvements to `HashMap` since the last time `Hashtable` was touched.

Answer (score 0):

I'll say this before answering the question: **do not ever use `Hashtable` anymore**. `Hashtable` is a legacy tool from Java 1.0, before the superior collections framework introduced with Java 2 going onwards.

If you require a simple hash map, use `HashMap`. If you require performing thread-safety, use `ConcurrentHashMap`. If you require plain basic and non-performing thread-safety, wrap a `HashMap` into `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)`.

Now to actually answer the question as is, which is purely compare two specific classes without seeing the spectrum of possibilities:

## Yes, such scenarios exist

From the [`Hashtable` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.

1. So yes, `Hashtable` is appropriate for scenarios where you need a thread-safe implementation, but do not "desire" a *highly-concurrent* implementation. This, again strictly in the exclusive comparison between `ConcurrentHashMap` and `Hashtable`.
2. Also, if you need `Enumeration`<sup>[1]</sup>, `Hashtable` has a direct support, while you have to go through `Collections.enumeration(...)` for other `Map`s.

---

<sup>1. `Enumeration` is also a Java 1.0 class. Switch to `Iterator` (if using Java 2 to 7) or `Stream` (if using Java 8+)</sup>

Comment: This is incomplete advice because a `synchronizedMap(new HashMap())` is better than `Hashtable`.

Comment: Hashtable is outdated in my opinion